# Regex to match string between %

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm trying to match substrings that are enclosed in %'s but `preg_match_all` seems to include several at the same time in the same line.

Code looks like this:

```
preg_match_all("/%.*%/", "%hey%_thereyou're_a%rockstar%\nyo%there%", $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Which produces the following output.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => %hey%_thereyou're_a%rockstar%
            [1] => %there%
        )

)
```

However I'd like it to produce the following array instead:

```
[0] => %hey%
[1] => %rockstar%
[2] => %there%
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Replace the "`.`" in your regular expression with "`[^%]`":

```
preg_match_all("/%[^%]*%/", "%hey%_thereyou're_a%rockstar%\nyo%there%", $matches);
```

What is happening is that the "`.`" is "greedily" matching as much as it possibly can, including everything up-to the final % on the line. Replacing it with the negated character class "`[^%]`" means that it will instead match anything *except* a percent, which will make it match just the bits that you want.

Another option would be to place a "`?`" after the dot, which tells it "don't be greedy":

```
preg_match_all("/%.*?%/", "%hey%_thereyou're_a%rockstar%\nyo%there%", $matches);
```

In the above example, either option will work, however there are times when you may be searching for something larger than a single character, so a negated character class will not help, so the solution is to un-greedify the match.

Answer (score 4):

You're doing a greedy match - use `?` to make it ungreedy:

```
/%.*?%/
```

If a newline can occur inside the match, add the s (DOTALL) modifier:

```
/%.*?%/s
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a ? after the *:

```
preg_match_all("/%.*?%/", "%hey%_thereyou're_a%rockstar%\nyo%there%", $matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the star is greedy. That is, the star causes the regex engine to repeat the preceding token as often as possible. You should try .*? instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could try `/%[^%]+%/` - this means in between the percent signs you only want to match characters which are not percent signs.

You could also maybe make the pattern ungreedy, e.g. `/%.+%/U`, so it will capture as little as possible (I think).

Comment: More precisely, `/U` inverts the greediness of all quantifiers in the regex, so `/%.+%/U` is the same as `/%.+?%/`, and `/%.+?%/U` is the same as `/%.+%/`. http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Answer (score 1):

|%(\w+)%| This will work exactly what do you want.

Answer (score 0):

While the solution is to turn a greedy `.*` into a lazy `.*?` (or replace `.*` with `[^%]*`), you might also want to actually get rid of `%` symbols in the output.

In that case, you will need to use a capturing group and get `$matches[1]` if a match occurred:

```php
$str = "%hey%_thereyou're_a%rockstar%\nyo%there%";
if (preg_match_all("/%([^%]*)%/", $str, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches[1]);
}
// => Array( [0] => hey [1] => rockstar [2] => there )
```

Note that `print_r($matches[0]);` will output full matches, `// => Array( [0] => %hey% [1] => %rockstar% [2] => %there% )`. The `[^%]` pattern is a negated character class that matches any char other than a `%` char.

See [the PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/UCsBS).

**Variations**

If you need to make sure there are only letters, digits or underscores between `%` chars, you can use

```
"/%(\w*)%/"
```

If you want to match any chars other than `%` and whitespace between two `%` chars use

```
"/%([^\s%]*)%/"
```

The `[^\s%]*` pattern is a regex that matches any zero or more chars other than whitespace (`\s`) and a `%` char.