# RegEx: Get a string between % signs excluding the signs

Tags: javascript, regex

For instance, in the string

```
'apple %cherry% carrots %berries2%'
```

I want to extract the following:

```
[
 'cherry',
 'berries2'
]
```

I've tried with the following RegEx but they all include the % signs:

```
/%[a-zA-Z\d]+%/g
```

I've made this RegEx based on the ones I found here: [Regex to match string between %](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270682/regex-to-match-string-between)

In case that makes a difference, here's how I extract the strings: http://jsfiddle.net/pixy011/APab8/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
/[a-zA-Z\d]+(?=%)/g
```

`(?= ... )` is a positive lookahead, which basically means that it checks to make sure the contents are in the string, without actually capturing them.

The first `%` is not needed because `%` does not match `[a-zA-Z\d]`.

Test run:

```
var matches = 'apple %cherry% carrots %berries2%'.match(/[a-zA-Z\d]+(?=%)/g);
console.log(matches); // => ["cherry", "berries2"]
```

Comment: But it can cause problem if string has a `apple%` as well.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
var re = /%([^%]*)%/g,
    matches = [],
    input = 'apple %cherry% carrots %berries2%';
while (match = re.exec(input)) matches.push(match[1]);

console.log(matches);
["cherry", "berries2"]
```